# Why won't my model translation job succeed?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I had been successfully translating some zipped folders using the model derivative api, I made some changes to the assembly, and now they're failing, but I can't see a message that tells my why when I get the manifest.  The zipped folder is in the correct structure (the root file is in the base file), and the root file is declared.

The urn being sent/file being translated is:
dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Y29uZmlndXJhdG9ydGVzdDIvYzBlYTNkNDEtY2VhNS00MzNjLTk1Y2ItMWIzMTlmMGY4YTQ4cmVzdWx0LnppcA==

I can download this file - I've uploaded the zip folder here:
https://files.solidcad.ca/index.php/s/rwmdWWskbHnE8ya

And the job is being sent to:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job

These are the details the job are sent with:

```
let data = urn;
var buf = new Buffer.from(data, 'ascii'); 
var plain_buf = buf.toString('base64'); 

const resolvedTemplate = {
                        'input': {
                            "urn": plain_buf,
                            "compressedUrn": true,
                            "rootFilename": "PlaysetGA.iam"
                        },
                        'output': {
                            "destination": {
                              "region": "us"
                            },
                            "formats": [
                              {
                                "type": "svf",
                                "views": [
                                  "3d"
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                    };
```

Comment: Also, can you pass a level of detail into the model derivative api? For example,  rootFile would be something like "PlaysetGA.iam<iLogic>"

Comment: Could you retry again? I cannot reproduce this issue. Just upload your zip, submit the same job body for translation and it works as expected.